# Polymer object data binding not working

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to bind data to an object, but I'm not sure why it is not working. Appreciate if you could help. Thank you!

How I try to bind the data:

```
<mypolymer attributes.myarray='["A","B","C"]' attributes.mynestedobject.attack='{"physical": 50, "magic":10}'></mypolymer>
```

My polymer element:

```
        Polymer({
        is: "mypolymer",
        properties: {
            attributes: {
                type: Object,
                value: {
                    myarray: [],
                    mynestedobject: {
                            attack: {
                                physical: 0,
                                magic: 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )}
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot pass sub-properties to an attribute(HTML attribute). You'll have to pass complete `attribute` object(attribute as a property name might not work because of being a key word). Also its [recommended](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#configure-values) to use `function` to set values for `Object` and `Arrays` in Polymer as they make sure that for each instance new value is returned.

> When initializing a property to an object or array value, use a function to ensure that each element gets its own copy of the value, rather than having an object or array shared across all instances of the element.